# Why I cannot Filter my data by Dynamic Data?

Tags: wpf, dynamic-data

I want to filter out the data containing letter 1, 2, 3.

Here is my code.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Click="Button_Click">1</Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Click="Button_Click_1">2</Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Click="Button_Click_2">3</Button>
        </Grid>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <ListBox x:Name="LB">

            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
using DynamicData.Binding;
using DynamicData;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                SourceList.Add(i.ToString());
            }
            SourceList.Connect().Bind(this.BindableList).Subscribe();
            LB.ItemsSource = BindableList;
        }
        private readonly SourceList<string> SourceList = new SourceList<string>();
        public IObservableCollection<string> BindableList { get; } = new ObservableCollectionExtended<string>();

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SourceList.Connect().Filter(_ => _.Contains("1")).Bind(this.BindableList).Subscribe();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SourceList.Connect().Filter(_ => _.Contains("2")).Bind(this.BindableList).Subscribe();
        }

        private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SourceList.Connect().Filter(_ => _.Contains("3")).Bind(this.BindableList).Subscribe();
        }
    }
}
```

It seems it only sorts it but does not filter it. The data I don't need is still in the ListBox.

PS: I dislike ReactiveUI and I don't want to use Dynamic Data with this.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You should filter the ObservableCollectionExtended directly because it is the source of the ListBox.

Comment: @BionicCode But there is no any Filter method in ObservableCollectionExtended yet.

Comment: @MelonNG: Your code looks OK to me. Are yoy saying the `ListBox` is not filtered when you click on the buttons? Are you using version 18.4.44 of the `ReactiveUI.WPF` package?

Comment: @mm8 I never add ReactiveUI.WPF package. I dislike ReactiveUI and seems Dynamic Data can run without ReactiveUI.

Comment: @MelonNG: So what version of the `DynamicData` package are you using then?

Comment: @mm8 The newest one.

Comment: @MelonNG: The latest version of ReactiveUI seems to use DynamicData version 7.3.15. Version 7.14.2 works for me as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you gave, all new copies of the SourceList pipelines bind to the same ObservableCollection, so the strings just pile on to it, and it seems that the last one bound gets to dump its items first.

Dynamic Data library .Filter operator accepts an IObservable of filter predicates, so you can do this, when connecting:

```
 SourceList
     .Connect()
     .Filter(_filter)
     .Bind(this.BindableList)
     .Subscribe();
  ...
 private BehaviorSubject<Func<string, bool>> _filter = new(x => true);
```

And, then just push another filter on your button events:

````
```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     _filter.OnNext(_ => _.Contains("1"));
 }
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You should filter the `ObservableCollectionExtended` directly because it is the source of the `ListBox`.
Use the static [`CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.getdefaultview?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#remarks) method to obtain the collection's default view.
In WPF the binding engine will observe the default `ICollectionView` of the source collection. The `ItemsControl` will also work on the `ICollectionView`.
Therefore filtering, sorting and grouping in the view is usually done using the `ICollectionView`.

In your case, simply assign a filter predicate of type `Predicate<object>` to the `ICollectionView.Filter` property:

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  ICollectionView collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.BindableList);
  collectionView.Filter = item => (items as string).Contains("1");
}
```

Comment: This way using the origin CollectionViewSource of WPF but not Dynamic Data.

Comment: That's correct. You explicitly stated that you don't want to use the dynamic data library: *"PS: I dislike ReactiveUI and I don't want to use Dynamic Data with this"*